# jQuery event.preventDefault confusion

Tags: html, forms, jquery-selectors, jquery

I'm using jQuery.

On click the search button is used the flag to check if radiobutton is unchecked it will show `alert("enter the field")` otherwise do the task... and also I used `event.preventDefault();`

Here actually I'm using radiobutton in which I used gender label that contains two option male and female. Now the problem is when I checked  male radio button or female. Still it's showing enter the field. I think there must be something wrong in this part `if($('#gender').is(":not(:checked)"))`

here is my code:

```
$('#searchbutton').click(function(event){

    alert("ZZ");

    var flag3=0;
    if ($('#gender').is(":not(:checked)"))
    {
        flag3=1;
    }
    if( flag3==1)
       alert("Select the field first");
    event.preventDefault();

});

<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="male" /> Male<br />
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="female" /> Female
<input type="submit"  name="searchbutton" value="Search" id="searchbutton">
```

Answer (score 7):

You have several problems in your code.

- An **ID can only be used once** in a HTML document. You used `#gender` twice.
- You don't need to use another flag variable, you can run the `if` simply.
- In your second `if` you have not used `{}` brackets, thus `preventDefault` is always executing.

I suggest you do something like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" /> Male<br />
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" /> Female
<input type="submit"  name="searchbutton" value="Search" id="searchbutton">
```

and the jQuery:

```
$('#searchbutton').click(function(event){
    if ($('input[name="gender"]:checked').length < 1) {
       alert("Select the field first");
       event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/xg2jC/)

**Explanation**: The [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) will match `input`s whose `name` is `gender`, and the [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector only selects the ones that are checked. Then using [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) we can see how many elements were matched. If zero, that means that the use has not selected any of the options.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you are trying to make sure the user makes a selection on gender.

The immediate problem is that both `<input type="radio">`s have the same id. While it is proper to give them the same name, you *never give two elements the same id*.

Additionally, you should simply be checking if any of the radio buttons are checked. This is how I would write the above code:

```
$('#searchbutton').click(function (e) {
    if ($(':radio:checked[name="gender"]').length == 0) {
        alert("Select the field first");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```